# After using \newcommand, Undefined control sequence error persists

Tags: macros, errors, ieeetran

I am using `IEEEtran` for a conference paper. When I try to define the `\vicon` seen in the code, I get an

`Undefined control sequence error`.

Although not shown in this code, the same error pops up for a float inside of a `\newcommand` window as well. Any thoughts? I've used the exact same `\newcommand` commands in different article formats with no issues. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

% Trademarks, brand names, etc.
\usepackage{textcomp} % for reg/trademark symbols
\newcommand{\trademark}{\raisebox{5pt}{\tiny TM}\xspace}
\newcommand{\vicon}{\text{Vicon}\trademark\text{ }}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Text here...
\vicon

\end{document}
```

It results in three errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \vicon
Undefined control sequence. \vicon
Undefined control sequence. \vicon
```

Comment: You're missing the `xspace` package as well as the `amsmath` package! `\text` needs `amsmath`, besides that, you don't need `\text` at all here!

Comment: Thank you so much! I new it was something simple that I was blind to after looking at it so long! If you post as an answer, I'm more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `\texttrademark` command already, if this is too low, it can be raised of course. I suggest to use something like this and provide a scalable raising (using `0.5ex`, for example)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xspace}
% Trademarks, brand names, etc.
\usepackage{textcomp} % for reg/trademark symbols
\newcommand{\trademark}[1][0.5ex]{\raisebox{#1}{\texttrademark}\xspace}

\newcommand{\vicon}{Vicon\trademark}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Text here...
\vicon

\end{document}
```

[image]